# Camera Parameters shows wierd errors

Tags: android, parameters, nullpointerexception

The below flashlight code used to work properly earlier. but when I started the android IDE for next time. it shows `NullPointerException` Error in the specific line consist of Camera Parameters. I have tried every other conditions to trace the stack still I cant find any relevant solutions. Any help is appreciated.

I have also visited some of the related queries in the forum. one of which queries I have found useful but still It didn't work.

[Google results](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4_pOMnYbNAhWFr48KHcnqDuUQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F13709112%2Fgetting-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-start-flashlight&usg=AFQjCNG83rKPcYSxgFKUIDcZdSFEPFMTnQ&bvm=bv.123325700,d.c2I)

**Flashlight.java**

```
public void connectCameraService() {
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
        params = camera.getParameters(); //specific line shows NullPointerException Error.

    }
}
```

The above method also creates Error in Override methods.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    connectCameraService();
}
```

Comment: i had same issues , didnt find any solutions. jst add try catch blocks. its device specific issue

Comment: already done using try catch conditions still it doesn't work. isn't there any solutions to make it work. I have tried several times. now it is getting frustrating. hope someone could help it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think I have added every required aspects. what else should I add to be more specific.